# total prime divisors of every index in array

Tags: c++, primes

So I am writing a program which counts number of prime divisors of all numbers upto 2 million.
So logic is that all prime array index will have value 1 and all composite array index will have value of no. of prime divisors. Eg. pno[3] = 1 ;pno[4]=1; pno[6]=2 ; pno[9]=1 etc.

```
void prim(){
    
long int pno[20000001] = {0};  //initialise all as 0
    for(long i=1;i<=2000000;++i){
        if(pno[i]==0){            //check if no is prime
            
            
            for(long j=i;j<=2000000;++j){   
                
                if(j%i==0){  //if i(a prime) divides j(a composite) then increase 
                    ++pno[j];
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

But it is not working as expected and every value is set to 1 at end. What is the problem here?

EDIT: This problem has been solved by comment by James K polk. I was supposed to start with *i=2* and *j* should be incremented by *i*

Comment: `long int pno[20000001] = {0};  //initialise all as 0` This will more than likely blow out the stack memory.  Then you have a nested `for` loop that will execute 2000000000000 times.  Obviously, the way you are attempting to solve this problem is not right.

Comment: Read this: [integer/ prime factorization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)

Comment: You are starting at 1, this is a mistake. First of all 1 is not a prime, and secondly every number is divisible by 1. Start at 2. Also the j loop should increment by 'i' each iteration, not 1. So `for(long j=i;j<=2000000;j+=i)`.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Ohhh! Now I feel so stupid. Thank you so much. Your comment corrected my code.